# dimension over residue field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory

Sorry for my bad English.

Let $A$ be integral domain, and $k(\frak{p})$ be residue field of $\frak{p}\in $Spec $A$.

Let $M$ be $A$-module, and $f(\frak{p}):=$dim$_{k({\frak{p}})} M\otimes_A k(\frak{p})$.

Now, is for any $\frak{p}\in$ Spec$A$, $f({\frak{p}})\le f((0))$ true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume by 'for any' you mean 'for all' (otherwise the answer is obvious as we can just take $\mathfrak{p}=(0)$).
No; if $M$ is a torsion module we have $f((0))=0$ but if $M\ne0$ there are points $\mathfrak{p}$ with $f(\mathfrak{p})>0$. Take e.g. $\mathfrak{p}$ to be a maximal ideal with $\mathfrak{p}\supseteq\operatorname{Ann}(M)$, then $$f(\mathfrak{p})=\dim_{A/\mathfrak{p}}M\otimes_AA/\mathfrak{p}=\dim_{A/\mathfrak{p}}M/\mathfrak{p}M=\dim_{A/\mathfrak{p}}M>0$$
For a concrete example take $A=\Bbb Z$, $M=\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ where $p$ is a prime number.